# Nested If Statement not Returning Correct Message in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to have this VBA code execute checks on a sheet to make sure that first the always required cells are not empty(H6,X6,AH6,J8), then check for the TER code in cell AN8 if it is found I then want the additional cells (AA19,AA20 and J28) to be checked if they are empty. I have this code on sheet1, and have it setup to executed upon saving. I'm not getting any errors but this code keeps displaying my second msgbox of "A required field for a termination is missing..." even when TER is not found in cell AN8. What am I missing?

```
Sub CheckRequired()
    Dim celltxt As String
    celltxt = Sheet1.Range("AN8").Text

    If (Range("H6") = Empty) Or (Range("X6") = Empty) Or (Range("AH6") = Empty) Or (Range("J8") = Empty) Then
        MsgBox " A required field has not been populated, please enter the missing information in the highlighted field and save again. "
    ElseIf InStr(1, celltxt, "TER") Then
    ElseIf (Range("AA19") = Empty) Or (Range("AA20") = Empty) Or (Range("J28") = Empty) Then
        MsgBox " A required field for a Terminiation is missing, check highlighted required fields."
    Else
        MsgBox " The personnel change form has been successfully completed! "
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note, `IsEmpty` is the shorter way to check.

Comment: @BigBen `IsEmpty("") => False`, `"" = Empty => True`. `IsEmpty(0) => False`, `0 = Empty => True`.

Comment: @GSerg so wouldn't OP *really* want `IsEmpty` then, as if a cell contained 0 it would still show as "empty"? Or is that the point of your comment, that it's not just the shorter way to check, it's the right way to check?

Comment: @BigBen My point was that `IsEmpty` and `=` are not equivalent, so one can't say it's a shorter way. They yield different results. I don't know which of the results the OP wants.

Comment: @GSerg fair enough, point noted.

Comment: @GSerg - even better, *thanks* for pointing that out. One of my New Year's resolutions is to be nice on SO :-)

Comment: @BigBen the values in all the fields being checked are text so I thought that using IsEmpty and Empty would evaluate similarly, I am a novice when it comes to vba. But after looking it up I see what you mean, one refers to a default value and the other refers to no value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you engineer the code in a way similar to this?

```
Sub CheckRequired()
    Dim celltxt As String
    celltxt = Sheet1.Range("AN8").Text

    If (Range("H6") = Empty) Or (Range("X6") = Empty) Or (Range("AH6") = Empty) Or (Range("J8") = Empty) Then
        MsgBox " A required field has not been populated, please enter the missing information in the highlighted field and save again. "
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If InStr(1, celltxt, "TER") Then
        If (Range("AA19") = Empty) Or (Range("AA20") = Empty) Or (Range("J28") = Empty) Then
            MsgBox " A required field for a Terminiation is missing, check highlighted required fields."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    MsgBox " The personnel change form has been successfully completed! "

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using this the overall structure makes sense to me but I do not think the Nz function works in Excel VBA it returned an error. When I removed it the codes works but still will go the the successfully completed message when J28 is empty

Comment: Not sure why I over complicated this I replaced the Nz function with concatenating a blank  (Range("AA19") & "") = "". Lack of sleep definitely played a part in me wrappiing my head around this thanks for all the help!

Comment: Yes, I see now that Nz is an Access only thing. I'll edit the response so I don't potentially confuse someone in the future! :-).